# React.js: why setTimeout doesn't work changing jsx element

Tags: reactjs

It doesn't change the jsx element after setTimeout call. Not changing the content variable inside section jsx element. Note that I am using section element because it's part of my project.

```
function Any() {
  
let content = <p>No movies found</p>;
  setTimeout(() => {
    content = "";
  }, 2000);

  return (
      <section>{content}</section>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is changing the `content`, It's just not rendering it after it gets changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is changing the `content` to `''` but the component is not rendering it after it gets changed so it looks like it is not changing.

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-http-h4wtom?file=/src/App.js)

One way to do is to use `useState` here.

You should use `useEffect` here.

> React is smart enough to figure it out when to render and when to not. If you change state with the same primitive current state then react won't re-render it. otherwise without `useEffect` would have caused Infinite re-rendering. You can prevent it by passing `empty dependency array` to `useEffect`.

If you want to see the `Infinite re-rendering` Please see [`CODESADNBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-dan-xzinm2?file=/src/App.js)

```
function Any() {
    const [content, setContent] = useState(() => <p>No movies found</p>);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('changing state');
            setContent('');
        }, 2000);
    }, []);

    return <section>{content}</section>;
}
```

Comment: I got it, brother! I remember now! React doesn't re-render because of some variable changes. Thank you for your explanations. But I have a question. You said I have to use the useEffect hook. But I don't need to! It also works with state and changing state with setTimeout. Without the useEffect hook or without dependency array It doesn't create any loop!

Comment: That is because if you are setting same value as current value then react won't re-render it.

Comment: I've added sandbox link where you can see why `useEffect` is important.